# Delete sheets if their names belong to an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple sheets named like dates e.g 12-01-2015, 12-02-2015, .... etc. I would like to create a code that deletes specific sheets if their names are listed in an array.
I created a code but it does not work. My guess is it is related to incorrect statement listed in line starting with "If".
I would really appreciate any tip where I am going wrong

```
Sub DeleteSelectedSheets()

Dim i As Long
Dim Holidays() As Variant

Holidays = Array("12-3-2015", "12-4-2015")

    For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook

        If Worksheet(i).Name = Holidays(i) Then

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

                Sheets(i).Delete

            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You want `For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.worksheets` and remove the `(i)` from worksheet and add a `i=i+1` at end of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
Sub DeleteSelectedSheets()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim Holidays() As Variant
   Holidays = Array("12-3-2015", "12-4-2015")
       For i = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
           If Sheets(i).Name = Holidays(0) Or Sheets(i).Name = Holidays(1) Then
               Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                   Sheets(i).Delete
               Application.DisplayAlerts = True
           End If
       Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub DeleteSelectedSheets()

Dim Holidays As Variant
Holidays = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet5")

For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If UBound(Filter(Holidays, Sheet.Name)) > -1 Then
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       Sheet.Delete
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If     
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are making the effort to dim the variant array you may as well `Dim  sheet As Worksheet`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine!

With the exception, *that will happen regardless the code you are using*, where there is only one sheet left and you are trying to delete it, it'll throw an error message!

See the use of `LBound()` and `UBound()` :

```
Sub DeleteSelectedSheets()

Dim i As Long
Dim Holidays() As Variant
Dim wS As Worksheet

Holidays = Array("12-3-2015", "12-4-2015")

For Each wS In ActiveWorkbook
    For i = LBound(Holidays) To UBound(Holidays)
        If wS.Name <> Holidays(i) Then
        Else
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                wS.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next wS

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to simply try and delete the worksheet(s) named in the array. Of course, you will need to operate under an `On Error Resume Next` to guard against the condition where a worksheet named does not exist.

```
Sub DeleteSelectedSheets()

    Dim h As Long, Holidays() As Variant

    Holidays = Array("12-3-2015", "12-4-2015")

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For h = LBound(Holidays) To UBound(Holidays)
        Worksheets(Holidays(h)).Delete
    Next h

    'alternate delete entire array (they need to be all there, fail on partial)
    'Worksheets(Holidays).Delete

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```